# Web Service AET SII c# numero maximo de peticiones

Tags: aeat-sii

Buenos dias o Buenas tardes pero siempre Buenos!!

Queria saber el numero maximo de peticiones que se puede hacer al web service del SII ya que en mi servicio cuando realizo la peticion no me devuelve nada...
Tengo esto definido de la siguiente manera :

```
<binding name="siiBinding24" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
  <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

El custom binding lo tengo definido asi :

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="ServicioImportacionServiceSoapBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Gracias!!

Comment: Bueno para mas informacion mi customBinding esta definido asi